# hints on solving DE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve this DE?
$$ {dx \over x} = {dy \over y} = {dz \over z - a \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}$$
From the first part, I get $y = c_1x$. How to find the other solution?
The answer according to answer sheet is $ z + \sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2} = c_2$. Thank you for help.

Comment: Try putting $w^{2} = x^{2} + y^{2} + z^{2}$ and then use the identity

\begin{equation}
\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d}=\frac{e}{f}=\frac{k_{1} a + k_{2} c + k_{3} e}{ k_{1} b+ k_{2} d+ k_{3} f}. 
\end{equation}

Comment: @BabakSorouh the topic is "Simulatneous Equation of first order first degree"

Comment: @JayeshBadwaik wouldn't i get more variables from substitution?

Comment: No, basically you then eliminate $x$ and $y$ and solve for $w$ in terms of $z$. If you want more hint, I can give you so.

Comment: okay thanks ... let me try first.

Comment: @JayeshBadwaik i got pretty weird eqn $$ {dw \over dz} = 2 \left ( w^2 - az\sqrt w \over z - a \sqrt w\right )$$

Comment: You must have made different substitutions. I am getting the following. 

\begin{equation}
\frac{dw}{dz} = \frac{w-\frac{a}{2}z}{z-aw}
\end{equation}

I will write a partial answer for you.

Comment: Sorry for the $\frac{a}{2}$, it should be only a

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$ {dx \over x} = {dy \over y} = {dz \over z - a \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}$$ You get $y=c_1x$, so put it into the third fraction:
$$ {dx \over x} =  {dz \over z - a \sqrt{x^2+c_1^2x^2+z^2}}$$ $$ {dx \over x} =  {dz \over z - a \sqrt{(1+c_1^2)x^2+z^2}}={dz \over z - a \sqrt{Cx^2+z^2}}$$ which is homogeneous equation: $$(z - a \sqrt{Cx^2+z^2})dx=xdz, x\neq 0$$ by taking $u=\frac{z}{x}$, you get: $${-adx \over x} =  {du \over \sqrt{C+u^2}}$$ then integrating from both sides gives: $$\ln|u+\sqrt{C+u^2}|=-a\ln|x|+c_2$$ or $$\ln|z+\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}|=(1-a)\ln|x|+c_2$$ Are you sure, you don't have any information about that $a$?

Comment: no ... it isn't given ... must be some arbitrary constant. thank you for your effort

Answer (score 4):

Let

\begin{equation}
{\frac{dx}{x}} = {\frac{dy}{y}} = {\frac{dz}{z - a \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}} = K
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
{\frac{2xdx}{2x^{2}}} = {\frac{2ydy}{y^{2}}} = {\frac{2zdz}{2z^{2} - 2az \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}} = K
\end{equation}

Then
\begin{equation}
\frac{dx^{2}}{2x^{2}} = \frac{dy^{2}}{2y^{2}} = \frac{dz^{2}}{2z^{2} - 2az \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}} = K
\end{equation}

Adding all the three terms, we get
\begin{equation}
\frac{dx^{2} + dy^{2} + dz^{2}}{2x^{2} + 2y^{2} + 2z^{2} - 2az \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}} = K
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\frac{dw^{2}}{2w^{2} - 2az \sqrt{w^{2}}} = {\frac{2zdz}{2z^{2} - 2az \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}}
\end{equation}

Hence,
\begin{equation}
\frac{dw^{2}}{2w^{2} - 2az \sqrt{w^{2}}} = {\frac{dz}{z - a \sqrt{w^2}}}
\end{equation}

And then, 
\begin{equation}
\frac{2w dw}{2w^{2} - 2az w} = {\frac{dz}{z - a w}}
\end{equation}

And so,
\begin{equation}
\frac{dw}{dz}= {\frac{w - az}{z - a w}}
\end{equation}

Comment: looks like i really put up a different subs!!

Comment: Yeah, can happen. ;-)